# Problemas com troca de JPanel dentro de JDialog usando Swing

Tags: java, swing, jdialog

Estou com um problema em um sistema que estou desenvolvendo com relação a troca de telas. Desculpe o post extenso, mas não consegui explicar o problema de outra forma.

Ele possui um `JFrame` principal com um menu que são JButtons e um `JMenuBar`. Um desses JButtons abre um `JDialog` com outros JButtons que quando clico, ele redesenha um novo `JPanel` no lugar do `JPanel` atual desse `JDialog`.

O `JMenuBar` que está no `JFrame` principal representa a mesma coisa que os JButtons no menu por ser apenas uma forma alternativa de navegar pelo sistema. Tenho a mesma coisa representando esses menus, os detalhes da estrutura do `JMenuBar` não é relevante.

Então como já dito, quando clico em um `JButton` do `JPanel` que está no `JFrame` principal, ele abre um `JDialog` que possui um `JPanel` dentro dele com mais um menu de JButtons.

Quando clico em um desses JButtons, ele executa o redesenho de um novo `JPanel` dentro desse `JDialog` usando o código semelhante abaixo (o código abaixo está dentro de uma classe que estende `JDialog`) usando a instância `JDialog` criada no submenu anterior, já que nessa modalidade irei acessar a tela fazendo um redesenho de `JPanel` aproveitando a instância `JDialog` já existente:

```
    getContentPane().removeAll();
    getContentPane().add(new JScrollPane(jPanelQualquer));
    repaint();
    printAll(getGraphics());
```

Já, quando faço o acesso à mesma tela pelo `JMenuBar`, como faço acesso direto à tela, eu não faço um redesenho de `JPanel`, e sim abro uma nova janela usando um algoritmo semelhante ao de baixo (na mesma classe que estende `JDialog`) onde nesse caso foi-se criada uma nova instância de `JDialog` usando o `new JDialog()`:

```
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JDialog.HIDE_ON_CLOSE);
    setModalityType(ModalityType.MODELESS);
    setLocationRelativeTo(principalFrame);
    getContentPane().add(new JScrollPane(jPanelQualquer));
    setVisible(true);
```

Estou tendo um bug nesse cenário que não faço ideia do que pode ser pois o Java simplesmente não gera nenhum erro. Ele apenas não executa o que é para ser executado.

O que faço é, primeiro acesso a aplicação, acesso o submenu pelo `JButton` do menu principal, e acesso a tela pela forma de redesenhar o `JPanel` por intermédio do submenu. Até aí show de bola pois a tela é redesenhada. Aí o que faço é fechar o `JDialog` do submenu, e acessar esse submenu de novo pelo `JButton` do menu principal, e com o `JDialog` no submenu aberto, vou lá na barra de menu `JMenuBar` e acesso a tela diretamente (dessa forma ele cria um novo `JDialog` já com a tela desenhada, ou seja, estou com um `JDialog` com o `JPanel` da tela e outro `JDialog` com o `JPanel` do submenu com o `JButton` que redesenha o `JDialog` com esse mesmo `JPanel` da tela). Até aí ok também. Fecho o `JDialog` com o `JPanel` da tela, e com a outra `JDialog` ainda aberta do submenu tento acessar a mesma tela de novo (lembrando que esse submenu redesenha o `JPanel` no `JDialog` dele ao invés de criar uma nova instância).

Resultado: Nada acontece.

O que pode ser? Eu debuguei já e confirmei pelo algoritmo que quando faço isso, a instância do `JPanel` que é pra ele desenhar está intacto, ele meramente não redesenha o `JDialog`.

O fato de se instanciar um novo `JDialog`usando o mesmo `JPanel` que, depois de fechado, um outro `JDialog` queira usar, pode influenciar em algo?

Comment: Daniel. Um componente não pode estar sendo exibido em dois lugares ao mesmo tempo. Se queres exibir o mesmo JPanel em outro JDialog precisará de uma nova instância do mesmo. Eu não sei explicar exatamente pra você o porquê, li isso em um artigo. Vou pesquisar ele aqui e já lhe indico. No seu caso acredito que seja porque o JDialog ainda existe, só não está sendo exibido.

Comment: Mas acredito que você pode fazer o seguinte: `jdialog.remove(jpainel); ` antes de fechá-lo. Ai sim acredito que você pode estar exibindo ele em outro `JDialog`

Comment: @DanielChirattoSeabra, já conseguiu resolver a questão?

Comment: @Dener, perfeita a colocação! Fiz o teste e de fato, o problema estava em tentar reutilizar um mesmo objeto JPanel. Criando-se uma nova instância resolve o problema. Muito obrigado!

Comment: Ok. Vou transformar em resposta o post então! Que bom que ajudei!

Comment: @DanielChiurattoSeabra pronto, se lhe resolveu acredito que pode marcar como resposta.

Comment: @Dener, to marcando! Valeus garoto!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Daniel**

De acordo com a [documentação](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/toplevel.html) (<strike>não achei o artigo</strike>) componente não pode estar sendo exibido em dois lugares ao mesmo tempo.

> Each GUI component can be contained only once. If a component is
>   already in a container and you try to add it to another container, the
>   component will be removed from the first container and then added to
>   the second.

No seu caso acredito que seja porque o `JDialog` ainda existe, só não está sendo exibido. Então, para exibir o mesmo `JPanel` em outro `JDialog`, você precisará de uma nova instância do mesmo.